# opening password protected Excel files in MAC (no Win32 available)

Tags: python, excel

I am using python on MAC and can't therefore use win32 module. I am trying to open a password protected excel file for which I know the password. Is it possible?

Comment: If you can do it with `pywin32` on Windows, then you can do it with `appscript` on Mac. Better yet, for working with Excel, use [xlwings](http://xlwings.org/) (which builds upon `pywin32` and `appscript` to provide higher-level Excel support).

Comment: What happens is the following:

from xlwings import Workbook
Workbook('filepath.xlsx')

Then the "insert password" GUI of Excel pops up and I have to insert it by hand.
I am not sure there is a way to programmatically pass the Password...

Comment: The way you asked your question, I figured you could already solve your problem if you were on a Windows PC. There still might be a purely command-line solution, but if not, you can script the GUI: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153930/autohotkey-equivalent-for-os-x

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I have never tried on pywin32 (as I don't have a PC :) but I see that the equivalent of open_Workbook has a "password" variable that can be passed